# Add column in one dataframe from looking up another one

Tags: pandas

I am struggling with a good way for a solution to this problems.

I am having a dataframe 'orders', which has a time and price column. And I have another dataframe 'prices' which give me the markt price at any time.

```
import pandas as pd
prices = pd.DataFrame({'time': range(10), 'price': [20, 21, 22, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]})
orders = pd.DataFrame({'time': [3, 6, 8], 'orderPrice' : [20, 24, 18]})
```

And I want to add a column to 'order', let's call it 'marketPriceTime', which does:

- take the last row from 'prices', where the 'price' is equal to the orderPrice and it's time is <= the time of the order row.

So the result in this case would be:

```
ordersResult = pd.DataFrame({'time': [3, 6, 8], 'orderPrice' : [20, 24, 18], 'marketPriceTime': [0, 6, None]})
```

Comment: Please add expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) on `time` with `price` as ID:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(orders, prices.rename(columns={'time': 'marketPriceTime'}),
                    left_on='time', right_on='marketPriceTime',
                    left_by='orderPrice', right_by='price')
```

Now the subtlety is that both dataframes must be sorted by `time` for the `merge_asof` to work. If this is not the case, you must use:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(orders.reset_index().sort_values(by='time'),
                    prices.sort_values(by='time').rename(columns={'time': 'marketPriceTime'}),
                    left_by='orderPrice', right_by='price',
                    left_on='time', right_on='marketPriceTime'
                   ).set_index('index').reindex(orders.index)
```

Output:

```
   time  orderPrice  marketPriceTime  price
0     3          20              0.0   20.0
1     6          24              6.0   24.0
2     8          18              NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
prices = pd.DataFrame({'time': range(10), 'price': [20, 21, 22, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]}).sort_values(by='price')
orders = pd.DataFrame({'time': [3, 6, 8], 'orderPrice' : [20, 24, 18]}).sort_values(by='orderPrice')
pd.merge_asof(orders, prices, left_on='orderPrice', right_on='price').drop(columns=['price'])

   time_x  orderPrice  time_y
0       8          18     NaN
1       3          20     0.0
2       6          24     6.0
```

Comment: This is only working by chance here, the time should be the key, not the price (see my answer) ;)